# Self.username and password in Rails 3 Active Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, activeresource

Is the point of the self.username and self.password Active Resource fields to authenticate the application that wants to consume the API?  If this is correct I would still need a separate authentication system such as sessions or cookies to manage the end users who sign into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that the self.username and self.password for ActiveResource are used for authenticating with the remote service. They utilize HTTP Authentication to communicate.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html -- Authentication section.

Comment: Also, the self.username/self.password are class variables, so authorizing remote ActiveResources with per-user credentials may require some tinkering.